# Does SQLite support common table expressions?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

Does SQLite support common table expressions?

I'd like to run query like that:

```
with temp (ID, Path) 
as (
  select ID, Path from Messages
) select * from temp
```

Comment: No sadly however there might be an alternative to what you need the CTE for, can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Sqlite version 3.8.3 SQLite supports common table expressions.

[Change log](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html)

[Instructions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to integrate a "CTE to SQLite" translation layer in your application :

"with w    as (y) z" => "create temp view w as y;z"

"with w(x) as (y) z" => "create temp table w(x);insert into w y;z"

As an (ugly, desesperate, but working) example :
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/stonebig/baresql/blob/master/examples/baresql_with_cte_code_included.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support CTEs, window functions, or any of the like. You can, however, write your own user functions that you can call inside SQLite by registering them to the database with the SQLite API using **sqlite_create_function()**. You register them with the database, and then you can use them in your own application code. You can make an aggregate function that would perform the sum of a series of averages based on the individual column values. For each value, a step-type callback function is called that allows you to perform some calculation on the data, and a pointer for holding state data is also available.

Comment: SQLite now supports them.