# Select Top 1 row for distinct id sqlite

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, database, sqlite

I got following table content :

```
> id    text        time
>      1     Hi          2
>      2     Hello       1
>      1     Mr. SP      3
>      3     KK          1
>      2     TT          2
>      1     Sample      1 
>      1     App         4
```

and i need to select distinct values for id with text, hence output should be:

> ```
> id     text      time
>  1      App       4
>  2      TT        2
>  3      KK        1
> ```

Can anyone help me out with this query.

I'm using Sqlite

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.* 
from 
(
select id, max(time) as time
from yourtable
group by id) a inner join yourtable b on a.time = b.time and a.id = b.id
```

working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fbb87/5

Comment: Thanks @Milen!

can you please help me on this query :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577230/select-top-1-for-distinct-value-according-to-time

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the value with the maximum time.  The following is often an efficient way to get this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.time > t.time);
```

What this is saying is:  "Get me all rows from the table where the `id` does not have a row with a larger `id`".  With an index on `table(id, time)`, this is probably the most efficient way to express this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select id,[text], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [time] desc) as rn
from [table]) as cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: with cte as(
select id,[mytext], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [mytime] desc) as rn
from [mytable])
select * from cte where rn = 1 [ near "with": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: sqlite does not support cte expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593068/does-sqllite-support-common-table-expressions

Comment: I modified it, please check it now.