# Select top 1 for distinct value according to time

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I got following tables :

**tblMyFriends**

```
ID     FriendID     GroupID      Public
1        F1                       YES
2        F2                       YES
3        F3                       NO
3                     G1          YES
4                     G2          YES
6        F4                       NO
7        F5                       YES
8                     G3          NO
```

**tblMessages**

```
ID     FriendID     GroupID      MyMessage     MyTime
1        F1                        A1            2 
2        F4                        A2            3
3        F1                        A3            1
3                     G2           Y1            1
4                     G2           Y2            3 
6        F3                        A4            3
7        F3                        A5            4
8                     G3           Y3            5
9        F4                        A6            5
10       F4                        A7            6
```

I need to fetch the latest message(only Top 1) i.e. decreasing order of time.
Also, followed by the remaining list of friend or  group in my list

Hence, i will need query which will return following output:

**tblOutput**

```
ID     FriendID     GroupID      MyMessage     MyTime
    1        F4                        A7            6 
    2                     G3           Y3            5
    3        F3                        A5            4
    4                     G2           Y2            3
    5        F1                        A1            2
    6        F2                                      0
    7        F5                                      0    
    8                     G2                         0
```

i'm using SQLite

Comment: Have you tried anything, my friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get records for friends/groups that do not have messages, use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join).

To get a single key, which makes joining easier, use the [coalesce function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce).
(This requires that the empty fields are NULL.)

To get one result record for each group of records use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT tblMyFriends.FriendID,
       tblMyFriends.GroupID,
       tblMessages.MyMessage,
       MAX(tblMessages.MyTime)
FROM tblMyFriends
LEFT JOIN tblMessages
       ON COALESCE(tblMyFriends.FriendID, tblMyFriends.GroupID) =
          COALESCE(tblMessages.FriendID,  tblMessages.GroupID)
GROUP BY tblMyFriends.FriendID,
         tblMyFriends.GroupID
```

This requires SQLite 3.7.11 or later; otherwise, the MyMessage values will not be from the same record that matches the MAX.