# SQLite with clause gives error near ")": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I have tried to run this SQlite code

```sql
WITH taulukko1 AS (
select Vuosi, Alue from testaus.Testidata
)
select * from taulukko1;
```

It always gives the error "[11:51:12] Error while executing SQL query on database 'testaus': near ")": syntax error".

I do not understand what is wrong?

Comment: What Sqlite version? Check -> [Does SQLite support common table expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23820079/7450780)